# Redirecting Sharepoint login page or display login web part

Tags: sharepoint, redirect, authentication, web-parts, fba

I have enabled FBA for my Sharepoint site and i want to add a login page or webpart either one of them.

Currently my site directly goes to Default.aspx and displays information and webparts (which display error messages)

**What i want is:** Either set my default page to the Login Page or if there is a way not to display anything on my default page other than a login web part?

I want users to login their details before they enter the default page?

Any solutions e.g. redirects, webparts or anyother will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As you enabled Forms Based Authentication (FBA), can't you just change your login page?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/_layouts/mycustomlogin.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Rubens! Basically at the moment i have         <authentication mode="Windows"/>
 <identity impersonate="true" />
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>

and what basically happens is when a user opens http://mysite/Testpage.aspx - the webparts are displayed with a message 'you are not authorised to view the webpage' what is want is that they should not be able to see the page completely...i hope this make sense - please let me know if it doesn't once again thanks for your help.

Comment: hmm, but you said you enabled FBA; how do your users login?

Comment: basically i have 2 zones 1 is default and the second is Extranet and in Central Admin i have defined the default as Windows and Extranet as Forms. I have anonymous enabled on both of them. Am i doing anything wrong? Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

A setup to match your description might look something like this:

Default Zone, Windows Auth, No Anonymous Access (usually)

Extranet, FBA, maybe anonymous access depending on what you're trying to do

A page that you don't want "the public" to be able to see at all should probably require authentication (no anonymous access).  Does this help?

Comment: makes perfect sense but when i try change the settings in my Central Admin it gives me errors - could you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625906/reset-or-configure-sharepoint-central-administration and let me know if you can help please?

Answer (score 1):

It definitely has something to do with your Anonymous Access - try to configure that appropriately.